# Possible ways to get the day before the 26 weeks of the current day?

Tags: c#, datetime

I wish to get the date before the 26 weeks of the current day via C#.

Any one provide me suggestions on the way to get the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could try this:

Since 26 weeks is 26 x 7 days, you can use `AddDays` on any given `DateTime` object.

```
var result = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-26 * 7);
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(result.DayOfWeek);
```

Output:

> 5/14/2018 12:44:36 PM
>
> Monday

See [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netframework-4.7.2), and note:

> The value parameter can be negative or positive.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean literally 26 weeks of seven days each, you can do it like this:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7 * 26)
```

Comment: Thank u for your response. Worked +!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-26 * 7);
var result2 = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(-26 * 7, 0, 0, 0));
var result3 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-26 * 7 * 24);
var result4 = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(26 * 7, 0, 0, 0));
var result5 = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 26 * 7 * 24, 0, 0));
```

And so one.